# There is already an object named '#TempTableName' in the database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored Procedure, I am moving final records to my temp table in `IF ELSE` statement

**Example**

```
IF(Condition)
BEGIN

     IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Records') IS NOT NULL  DROP TABLE #Records

     SELECT *
     INTO #Records
     FROM TableName

     SELECT * FROM #Records
END
ELSE
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Records') IS NOT NULL  DROP TABLE #Records

     SELECT *
     INTO #Records
     FROM TableName

     SELECT * FROM #Records
END
```

My StoredProcedure is exactly the same as the above format. It throws the error `There is already an object named '#Records' in the database.`

Comment: Just don't use this pattern blindly. Given what you posted, there is no reason to dump the contents of one table into a newly created temp table and then to immediately select all of those rows from that temp table (presumably to return to the caller).

Answer (score 1):

Place your if condition out of the if block....

```
  IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Records') IS NOT NULL  DROP TABLE #Records


 IF(Condition)
BEGIN
     SELECT *
     INTO #Records
     FROM TableName
     SELECT * FROM #Records
END
ELSE
     SELECT *
     INTO #Records
     FROM TableName
     SELECT * FROM #Records
END
```

OR

Just drop this temp table first in your db once then create your stored procedure

```
  drop table #records
```

Execute this then create your stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed. Even though the SP has a drop statement before I try to create the temp table.  Actually what I was missing is 'tempdb..'. I didn't seem to find that when looking though Microsoft documentation; would have saved me a few hours if I had .

Answer (score 0):

Try this will help you

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Records') IS NOT NULL  DROP TABLE 
#Records

SELECT top 1 * INTO #Records FROM TableName where 1=0;

IF(1=1)
  BEGIN

   INSERT INTO #Records
   select * FROM TableName;

   SELECT * FROM #Records;
 END
ELSE
 BEGIN

   INSERT INTO #Records
   select * FROM TableName;

   SELECT * FROM #Records;
 END
```

Answer (score 0):

because while compiling SP by SQL object already found in IF condition and same time you are creating same table name in else. so it won't work.

I generally use following way

```
SELECT top 0 *
         INTO #Records

    IF(Condition)
    BEGIN

    INSERT INTO #Records
         SELECT *
         FROM TableName

         SELECT * FROM #Records
    END
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO #Records
         SELECT *
         FROM TableName

         SELECT * FROM #Records
    END

DROP TABLE #Records
```

You just execute 
`DROP TABLE #Records` first and then try to run this SP